# jQuery Propagation and multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, propagation

-- UPDATE --

I was a little bit stupid, the child UL's were covering the parent list (opacity fadeout), so I couldn't click the groups after i clicked them once. Oops! Anyhow thanks for helping me out guys!

---

The problem with jQuery propagation is something everyone is wrestling with. But here is my case which I can find nowhere to fix (or maybe I am dumb to not look at the right places or my jQuery skills just aren't good enough to understand).

The base case is that I have some groups, and in the groups there are several options. when you click on one of the groups, the options will pop up. BUT, when I click one of the options the whole popping up activity fires again, because it are the children of the parent, and so he recognizes the class where the children are catched in.

My HTML looks as follows:

```
<div id="buttons">
        <ul>
            <li class="group">Group 1
                <ul>
                    <li class="link">Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="group">Group 2
                <ul>
                    <li class="link">Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="group">Group 3
                <ul>
                    <li class="link">Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="group">Group 4
                <ul>
                    <li class="link">Link</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I guess that looks quite simple and nothing is wrong with that I suppose. It are just lists nested within lists.

But then my jQuery code. It looks like this:

```
$(".group").click(function(event) {

    // if ($(event.target).is('ul li ul li')) return false;

    $(".group").children("ul").animate({top: 0, opacity: 0}, 200);
    var liHeight = ($(this).children("ul").children("li").height())+20;
    var totalOptions = $(this).children("ul").children("li").length;
    var combinedHeight = totalOptions * liHeight;
    var slideIn = -(16+combinedHeight) // formula doing math on slidedistance
    $(this).children("ul").animate({
                            top: slideIn,
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 600);

    /*
    $(".link").click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    */

});
```

What it actually does is:

1. resetting the group children to default top position
2. getting the clicked group
3. getting height of the total child ul of the target group
4. preparing the distance for the animation
5. firing the animation

There is no problem coming along with that and all works as I wants, but when I click on the `li`s within the `ul`s, it just keeps firing the animation, and that is not part of the plan.

I commented out 2 blocks of code as you might have noticed. That are 2 different ways for controlling propagation I found while stumbling the internet for a relative problem with answer. Both give no good result though. What happens is that the propagation actually stops, but makes it also unable to click different groups.

That is the problem in a nutshell. I think I just need to have one or two lines to add, but I just can't think of what should fit, almost tried everything that came to my mind.

Also, if you can't find any answers but have some feedback on the code markup or something, it's also welcome (I'm a student in interaction design / web development,  so I would appreciate that too :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not install the click handler on the `.group` item, but only on the toggle element.

```
<li class="group">
    <a class="toggle">Group 2</a>
    <ul>
        <!-- contents to show & hide -->
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
$(".toggle").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next()... // to reference the ul
})
```

Comment: That sounds like something I haven't though about yet, maybe that is something i could try!

Comment: Isn't that text "Group 2" the element where you want the click to happen? The solution shouldn't read strange.

Comment: Yes, that certainly is. However, I tried it and still can't click the next groups to show their contents.

Comment: Like in my post update, i resetted the top position of the list items to 0, which made them lying on top of the groups so I couldn't click them anyways :) anyhow, I used your tip, it's a very good and much easier workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just move the following code outside of the `.group` click handler:

```
$(".link").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Full code:

```
$(".group").click(function(event) {

    // if ($(event.target).is('ul li ul li')) return false;

    $(".group").children("ul").animate({top: 0, opacity: 0}, 200);
    var liHeight = ($(this).children("ul").children("li").height())+20;
    var totalOptions = $(this).children("ul").children("li").length;
    var combinedHeight = totalOptions * liHeight;
    var slideIn = -(16+combinedHeight) // formula doing math on slidedistance
    $(this).children("ul").animate({
                            top: slideIn,
                            opacity: 1
                        }, 600);
});


$(".link").click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I think he should also make sure he has display:block; so you can't click through the letters and such and access the parent element.

Comment: @maxedison it didn't work :( got the same effect as if I place it whithin the click handler..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for the tip :) didn't solve it also. But usefull!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an alternative way of the `click` listener. If you use the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery - you can delegate the listener to the child element. Like so:

```
$('#buttons').on('click', 'li', function(e){
    var li = $(this);

    if(li.hasClass('group')){
        alert('group was clicked');
    }
    else if(li.hasClass('link')){
        alert('link was clicked');
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

A live example of this code is here - http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/YWzxB/

Notice: if you delete the `stopPropagation` part on the `link` delegation - you'll see *two* alerts. First - for the `link` and then - for the `group`.

Comment: The idea is right, but it seems he wants the user to click on the text node before the `ul`, not on the `li.link`

Comment: This certainly brings me somewhere, but still cannot click the groups after, it looks like he recognizes the groups as links (because if the event has been fired, i get the alert "link was clicked" on a group class. But really thanks!